# Работоспособность кода расчета размера видимой части экрана без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

В процессе вёрстки сталкиваюсь с необходимостью знать размер видимой части экрана. Для этого я добавляю следующий код:

```js
var html = document.documentElement;
var debugging_block = document.getElementById('debugging');
debugging_info = "Размер видимой области: " + html.clientWidth + "х" + html.clientHeight;
debugging_block.innerHTML = debugging_info;
```

```html
<div id='debugging'></div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы данный код работал без обновления страницы, аналогично  media query в CSS?

Comment: пока на ум пришло только обернуть код js  в window.onresize = function() {}  -  но тогда он работает только после изменения окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> обернуть код js в window.onresize = function() {} - но тогда он
>   работает только после изменения окна

Создайте отдельную функцию с этим кодом.

```
function Foo()
{
  var html = document.documentElement;
  var debugging_block = document.getElementById('debugging');
  debugging_info = "Размер видимой области: " + html.clientWidth + "х" + html.clientHeight;
  debugging_block.innerHTML = debugging_info;
}
```

Затем используйте её в качестве обработчика двух событий

```
window.onload = Foo;
window.onresize = Foo;
```

Тогда, будет работать не только при изменении размера, но и сразу при загрузке.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/02mf0jg9/ ...не получается ( я слаб в js, но попытка ставить скобки.... то же ни к ему не привела...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/02mf0jg9/1/ вот так работает)))